# After copying the whole folder, they wont show up

Tags: joomla, ftp, joomla3.0

I've been working on a website by building it on Joomla. I built it locally with XAMPP and today I copied the files to the directory on the FTP to publish the website and went to the admin panel and there are no plugins or templates, this is weird because I copied the whole folder and imported the database. Already did this twice but it seems to be another error than copy error.

**Attention:**
I did not install the template and plugins after getting the joomla online, I just copied it to the ftp

[image: pic of the files]

Comment: Check your permissions and ownership in the directories. They should match the main ones.

Comment: nope that isnt it, akeba solved :)

Comment: While Akeeba Backup is best options, you may also use discover extensions that are copied over to Joomla installation, but not installed: `Admin > Extensions > Extension Manager > Discover`

Comment: well thanks for the tip, this was my first time using joomla, I usually work with Wordpress and never had problems with this kind of stuff :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to use a tool like [Akeeba Backup](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-backup.html). This will automate the process and resolve most common issues when moving a Joomla site.